# connecting Visual studio Code C# to My Sql

Tags: mysql, c#, visual-studio-code

I'm working on Ubuntu 17.04, i just installed Visual Studio code, C# and a debugger, the IDE is working very nice, in order to complete the development of the project i'm working on, i need to connect to MySQL on my local machine, but i cant fined any extension that does it, does there is one that does it, or if not, how can i connect to my MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Install the [vscode-database](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bajdzis.vscode-database) will support mysql database.

Read this [Long Guide](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2017/02/17/vs-code-extensions-mssql-and-vscode-database)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you need to install MySQL or MariaDB onto the local machine with:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

or for MariaDB

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server
```